# Proof that $y+y^2=x+x^2+x^3$ has no integer root (except $x=0$).

Tags: number-theory, roots

> Proof that $y+y^2=x+x^2+x^3$ has no integer root (except $x=0$).

$LHS = (y-x)(y+x+1) = x^3$, and $gcd(y-x, y+x+1)$ seems to be $1$.
So there are two integers $a,b$ that could make $$y-x=a^3, y+x+1=b^3,x = ab \not = 0$$
Then we have $$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
b^3-a^3=2ab+1 \\
(b-a)(b^2+ab+a^2) = 2ab +1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

But I don't know how to prove that it's impossible to have any integer root ($x \not = 0$).

Comment: You could rewrite $ 1+y+y^2 = 1+x+x^2+x^3 $ and proceed $ { y^3-1 \over  y-1 } = { x^4-1 \over x-1 } $ With this notation We've had a question recently in MSE which I think has also answers. Has as "tag" something like `diophantine-equations` or similar...

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1290905p6828857), and also [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1567727p9607373) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h401315p2234756).